# How to configure a testnet node to be pruned?

Tags: bitcoind, testnet, pruning, bitcoin.conf

I have a testnet VM node running. As I have only limited resources, I did set `pruned=1000` in the bitcoin.conf file, so the blockchain is pruned down to 1GB. But when I run bitcoind and it downloads the blockchain, I get the error, that no more space is available after downloading 80% or so.
So my question: How do I make sure that the pruned mode is actually enforced?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bitcoin.conf option must be `prune=1000`, not `pruned=1000`. If you specified the latter, it was probably ignored.
You could reduce the number up to 550 (MiB), bitcoind won't start if you choose a lower number.